# How to outline traces in graphics

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly, pcb-layers

I've been searching online with no luck.

I'm using KiCad and I want to outline my traces with graphics similar to the image shown below. Is there a function within KiCad that does this or is this a function from another program?

I’ve updated the picture to point to the darker areas surrounding  the traces, and I’m trying to replicate this in KiCad.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the designators at the bottom of the shown pcb?

Comment: Have you tried googling *KiCad silkscreen* ? Or do you mean the flooded areas on the PCB?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean with "graphics" and outline traces. Do you mean solder mask? Silk screen? Something else?

Comment: Look up "ground  pour".

Comment: Do you want to replicate/copy an existing PCB?

Answer (score 2):

The "darker areas" are where the copper is etched away between the trace and the [Ground plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_plane).

This is a side-effect of well, manufacturing a PCB. So, just add a ground plane and you'll get this exact effect.